# Get the filename and filepath of the code running

Tags: sas

I need to get the current running SAS program's name and file path into local variables. I accomplished that using the `SAS_EXECFILEPATH` and `SAS_EXECFILEPATH` commands. I ran this through windows SAS and it worked.

But when i tried to run this on the server in batch mode, it failed. I then tried the `&_SASPROGRAMFILE` parameter, which ran fine on `SAS EG`, but fails when I trigger it on the server in batch mode.

Is there a possible way to accomplish this in batch mode on the server?

Answer (score 3):

You might be looking for `%sysfunc(getoption(sysin))` ([Usage Note 24301: How to retrieve the program name that is currently running in batch mode or interactively](http://support.sas.com/kb/24/301.html)), if you start the program with `sas -sysin path/to/file.sas`.

Comment: Thanks @Nickolay, but the sysin option does not work on EG then, don't we have any option that works on the server and locally on EG as well?

Comment: Otherwise i'll have to code separately for Base SAS, SAS EG and the sevrer.

Comment: @Rhea: I think not, otherwise the Usage note I referenced would have mentioned it. You wrap the code handling all the cases you're interested in a macro to avoid repeating this logic over and over.

Comment: Okay, I guess then there's no other choice, i'll have to check for the run environment and then calculate the program details accordingly. Thanks @Nickolay

Comment: sysin only show the path of the program invoked even when inside included program

Comment: Sure, `%include` doesn't affect `getoption(sysin)`. I can't think of a solution for SAS Macro.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is delayed but you could generate a macro that calls on the right code depending on if you are running the program in the editor or in batch mode. Art Carpenter created a great macro that solves this issue.

```
%macro ExecPrg;

%if %sysfunc(getoption(sysin)) ne %str() %then %do;
  /* Batch Execution */
%sysfunc(getoption(sysin))
%end;
%else %do;
  /* Interactive Execution */
  %sysget(SAS_EXECFILEPATH)
%end;
%mend execprg;
```